# mdadm alerts configuration

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a dedicated server in OVH. mdadm is installed and configured automatically, but I need configure scans and alerts.

I checked some guides in internet but I'm not safe that this is the correct steps, please can you confirme me this is correct?:

1- Send alert to root email if some disk have problems: **nano /etc/mdadm.conf -> add to bottom "MAILADDR root"**

2- Enable the scan and monitoring: **mdadm --monitor --scan --daemonize**

3- Enable the scan and monitoring when restart the server: **nano /etc/rc.d/rc.local -> add to bottom "mdadm --monitor --scan --daemonize"**

4- Change rc.local permits: **chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local**

Question 1: This is correct?, I need do anything more for mdadm monitorize, scan and alert me if any disk in RAID have problems?.

Question 2: I need reboot the server after do this steps?.

Thank you again. Have a nice day!

Comment: Anybody can help me please?. Thank you very much.